# Finding tests within groups with results - Oracle 12

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to determine if any container group has a test in a group of many with any result .

I feel I need a simple loop, but cannot frame it in my mind. There is a group of 4 tables connecting all the dots from the container through the tests and then to results.

Table `con_group1` contains *container_groups*. Table `containers2` contains *container_group_ids* and individual *container_ids* and *test_group* ids. Table `test_groups3` contains *test_group_ids* and  *test_ids*, table `tests4` contains *test_ids* and *result_id*. `Table 5` contains results.

I need to determine which containers have tests that all have results. Does not matter what the result is, just whether there is a result for every test contained in a container.

```
------------------------------------
|  Container  |   Test   |  Result |
------------------------------------
|    8        |    69    |         |
|    9        |    87    |    8    |
|    8        |    45    |         |
|    6        |    58    |         |
|    9        |    95    |    5    |
------------------------------------
```

**Desired result:**

```
------------------------- 
| Container Group |           |
-------------------------
|        2     |    done   |
|        1     |    open   |
|        3     |    open   |
-------------------------

{CREATE TABLE CONTAINERS2
(CON_GROUP  NUMBER(10),
CONTAINER  NUMBER(10));

CREATE TABLE CON_GROUP1
(CON_GROUP  NUMBER(10));
CREATE TABLE TESTS4
(RESULT_ID  NUMBER(10),
  TEST       NUMBER(10));

CREATE TABLE TEST_GROUPS3
(CONTAINER  NUMBER(10),
TEST       NUMBER(10));

INSERT INTO CONTAINERS2(CON_GROUP, CONTAINER) VALUES (1, 8);
INSERT INTO CONTAINERS2(CON_GROUP, CONTAINER) VALUES (3, 6);
INSERT INTO CONTAINERS2(CON_GROUP, CONTAINER) VALUES (2, 9);
INSERT INTO CON_GROUP1(CON_GROUP) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO CON_GROUP1(CON_GROUP) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO CON_GROUP1(CON_GROUP) VALUES(3);

 INSERT INTO TESTS4(RESULT_ID, TEST) VALUES (8, 87);
 INSERT INTO TESTS4 (RESULT_ID, TEST) VALUES (NULL, 45);
 INSERT INTO TESTS4 (RESULT_ID, TEST) VALUES(NULL, 58);
 INSERT INTO TESTS4  (RESULT_ID, TEST) VALUES (NULL, 69);
 INSERT INTO TESTS4 (RESULT_ID, TEST) VALUES(5, 95);

 INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPS3(CONTAINER, TEST) VALUES(8, 45);
 INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPS3 (CONTAINER, TEST) VALUES(9, 87);
 INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPS3 (CONTAINER, TEST) VALUES(6, 58);
 INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPS3(CONTAINER, TEST) VALUES (8, 69);
 INSERT INTO TEST_GROUPS3(CONTAINER, TEST) VALUES (9, 95);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series of LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY can do the job:

```
SELECT cg.con_group,
       max( CASE WHEN result_id IS NULL
                 THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed'
            END ) As Result
FROM con_group1 cg
LEFT JOIN CONTAINERS2 co ON co.con_group = cg.con_group 
LEFT JOIN TEST_GROUPS3 tg ON tg.container = co.container
LEFT JOIN TESTS4 t4 ON t4.TEST = tg.TEST
GROUP BY cg.con_group
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a705/1)

```
| con_group | result |
|-----------|--------|
|         1 |   Open |
|         3 |   Open |
|         2 | Closed |
```

---

> ... need to determine which container groups qualify, not containers..
>   containers will have to be qualified to get the container groups
>   qualification..

If I understand this requirement well, You need:

```
SELECT cg.con_group,
       co.CONTAINER,
       max( CASE WHEN result_id IS NULL
                 THEN 'Open' ELSE 'Closed'
            END ) As Result
FROM con_group1 cg
LEFT JOIN CONTAINERS2 co ON co.con_group = cg.con_group 
LEFT JOIN TEST_GROUPS3 tg ON tg.container = co.container
LEFT JOIN TESTS4 t4 ON t4.TEST = tg.TEST
GROUP BY cg.con_group,
         co.CONTAINER
```

Demo: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7a705/4)

```
| con_group | container | result |
|-----------|-----------|--------|
|         1 |         8 |   Open |
|         2 |         9 | Closed |
|         3 |         6 |   Open |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of tests per container and the number of tests with results per container and compare the two result sets. This solution uses subqueries to get the two counts, and an outer join (because maybe a group of tests has no results at all):

```
with tests as 
    ( select tg.container
             , count(tg.test) as tst_cnt
      from test_groups3 tg
      group by tg.container )
  , results as  
    ( select tg.container
             , count(tr.test) as tst_cnt
      from test_groups3 tg
           join tests4 tr
               on tr.test = tg.test 
      group by tg.container )
select tests,container
       , case when tests.tst_cnt = results.tst_cnt
             then 'done'
         else 'open' 
         end as status
from tests
     left join results
     on tests.constainer = results.container
/
```

Comment: looks great from a distance. I will apply to my data/table structure and mark anwered if it gives me what I need...Thank you!!

Comment: your code brought to light the fact that I misstated the issue... I need to determine which container groups qualify, not containers.. containers will have to be qualified to get the container groups qualification..